# Многопоточное программирование (класс Thread)

Tags: java, многопоточность

Решил посмотреть как работает метод start().
Не нашел ни одного упоминания о методе run().

Cледовательно вопрос: Каким образом, при вызове start() срабатывает метод run()?

```
public synchronized void start() {
    if (threadStatus != 0)
        throw new IllegalThreadStateException();

    group.add(this);

    boolean started = false;
    try {
        start0();
        started = true;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (!started) {
                group.threadStartFailed(this);
            }
        } catch (Throwable ignore) { }
    }
}
```

доп. инфо: Увидел строку где находится вызов нового потока, но как в этом потоке он передает на выполнение содержимое run() - я не увидел. Может все на поверхности, но не знаю... сам не вижу связь между start() и run(), кроме как исключительно с точки зрения теории.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Врядли вы увидите это в рамках JRE. Потоками управляет JVM(будучи сама написанная на C++, если я ничего не путаю), она создает поток используя ресурсы ОС, и уже в рамках потока созданного ОС, прокидывает управление интерфейсу Runnable